# Developer Mode ON in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to turn developer Mode ON which I turned off during installation. I cannot find setting options on interface or from quick launch or from options to turn it on. The only thing I am finding is Account Settings, but not settings which have security and updates.

Comment: That doesn't mean much.  My crystal ball says that you are talking about the Windows 10 system setting.  Just type "use developer features" in the Cortana search box.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\TypeScriptLanguageService (or create the key if it does not exist).
Create a new DWORD (32-bit) Value with the name EnableDevMode.
Right click the EnableDevMode value and Modify it.
Change the value data to 1.